# why is pip so SLOW to download? (how to troubleshoot?)

Tags: python, download, pip

I can wget e.g. [python coverage](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/coverage/coverage-3.6.tar.gz#md5=67d4e393f4c6a5ffc18605409d2aa1ac) and pip install the package locally quickly and without any problem, but `pip install coverage` takes *forever*.  Using pip 1.3.1 in a virtual env on Ubuntu 12.04.  Any idea what could be the hold-up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Donald Stufft answered in [pip issue 864](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/864), it happens because `pip` crawls a lot of pages looking for package sdists, and this behavior was inherited from `easy_install`. Some packages do not work if you remove that feature, and some guys started a new PEP to remove this external links behavior: [PEP 438 - Transitioning to release-file hosting on PyPI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0438/)

Donald said *"Until PEP438 is implemented you can also use the restricted API of Crate.io, pip install -i https://restricted.crate.io/ this will only install releases that are directly hosted."*

But as [Marcus Smith mentioned in the virtualenv mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/python-virtualenv/UDWsPHKHvjY), you can download the package and its dependencies, and them ignore PyPI and use your download directory: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#fast-local-installs

---

*Example using https://restricted.create.io to avoid the external links behavior:*

```
$ pip install -i https://restricted.crate.io/ coverage
```

---

References:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/864
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0438/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/python-virtualenv/UDWsPHKHvjY

Comment: Just using the ``--download`` option for ``pip install`` didn't seem to help, but using https://restricted.crate.io/ did.