# PIP slow to download packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

Is there a reason why downloading packages is slow using pip? I've tried downloading tensorflow, jupyterlab, scikit-learn and they all start at 1.1MBps and slow down to just 35kbps. I have a 100Mbps download speed so I should be getting at least 5+ MBps. I'm not quite sure if it is a networking problem restricting my download. Using conda to download is slightly better but is still slow. Anything I should fix in order to increase my download speed? It is starting to take a lot of time especially when I create new environments because the same process starts all over again.

I've already checked and my download speed is as it should be it's 100MBps, but downloading through pip & conda is just extremely slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is pip so SLOW to download? (how to troubleshoot?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629061/why-is-pip-so-slow-to-download-how-to-troubleshoot)

Comment: What happens when you go to the pypi project page and download the file using your browser? Or another tool like wget

Comment: I am also frustrated by this issue and tend to use mamba as a drop-in replacement for conda to speed up downloads. Also (thankfully!) conda seems to have greatly increased its speed recently. Not very helpful if you *have* to use pip but hope it helps if you have the option to use something else.